# How to draw downward arrows emanating from a single objects (to show hierarchy)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, boxes

I would like to create a diagram using Latex showing something like this:

[image]

The text may also be in math mode.

In any case, how can this be done? One is idea: I can try to use \begin{center} \end{center} for the top most item (Fox Types) and create minipages for the stuff in the middle. Then use Tikz to create some arrows and carefully arrange them so they look as if linked together.

Is there a better idea/way to do this?

Comment: You should take a look at `nodes` and maybe `trees` i, Ti*k*Z, try something by yourself and come back to edit your question to insert what you tried and what you couldn't achieve. This type of drawing is very straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this could be a starting point, even if not fully accurate.

[image: some arrows]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    \tikzset{txtnode/.style={text width=3cm,outer sep=2pt}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
        \node (A) {Fox types};
        \node[below left= 2cm and 2cm of A,txtnode,anchor=north east] (B) {Brown Fox:\\Popular in Howard County, likes to eat Cherries};
        \node[below = 2 cm of A,txtnode,anchor=north] (C) {Black Fox:\\Lives in Yorkshire, can perform magic spells};
        \node[below right= 2cm and 2cm of A,txtnode,anchor=north west] (D) {Red Fox:\\Steals from chicken coop};
        
        \foreach \n in {B,C,D} \draw[line width=1pt,->] (A) -- (\n);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```